# Global sequence number for Event Hubs (Service Bus)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Does anyone know if there is a global sequence number for Events in Azure Event Hubs (part of Service Bus)?

I know that you can get the sequence no and the offset from EventData but that is only in order for the partition.  I need the sequence number across the whole event hub (ie all partitions).  Cheers

Comment: If you are looking for a number that tells you in what order events have been received (or processed) I think that it is not there. It would mean that there need to be extensive communication between partitions to determine the right number and that will have a negative impact on the performance.

Comment: You can use the "PartitionKey + SequenceNumber" to identify a message but no there is no global id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO** - there is no notion of Global Sequence Number for Event Hubs (ServiceBus). `SequenceNumber` is local to the `EventHubs Partition`. Same `SequenceNumber`'s can occur on 2 partitions.

Comment: Does this mean sequence numbers are unique to their partition? I.e. The same sequence number *can* appear in two different partitions of an EH? @sreeram

Comment: Yes @Steve, same seqNo can appear in 2 diff. Partitions.